# parallelizing a simple numpy computation

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing

I have a very simple numpy expression:

```
mat.prod(axis=1).max()
```

Will numpy use multiple cores to evaluate this?
If not, can I tell numpy to use multiple cores?

Would using `numexpr` be helpful here?

Comment: I think it would use SIMD vectorized CPU instructions (such SSE) when possible and compiled with such.  But multi-cores, no, not for the basic reduce-like methods.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24498178/understanding-the-difference-between-vectorizing-in-numpy-and-multi-threading-of